# Let f : Z+ → P(Z+) be the function defined by f(x) = {d ∈ Z+ : d divides x} for all x ∈ Z+

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let f : Z+ → P(Z+) be the function defined by

f(x) = {d ∈ Z+ : d divides x} for all x ∈ Z+.

Is f a one-to-one function? No

Is f an onto function? Yes

Which of the following is a well-defined and true statement.

(a) f−1({1, 2, 3, 6}) = 6.

(b) f−1({{1, 2, 3, 6}}) = 6.

(c) f−1({{1, 2, 3, 6}}) = {6}.

(d) None of the above.

I'm not sure I understand sets, particularly power sets well enough to answer the last part.

Comment: What have you tried? Math.stackexchange is not a place to post homework questions for people to solve.

Comment: Sorry, was still editing.

Comment: You certainly have this wrong. $f$ is injective (note that the max element of $f(x)$ is $x$) and not surjective (for what $x$ do we have $f(x) = \{4\}$?).

Comment: How can it be injective when nothing maps to the null set?

Comment: Please learn MathJax. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hey @SunshineTS! Since you seem to be a 4th year UQ student, probably in Software/Electrical Engineering it might pay to not go posting questions verbatim from your MATH1061 assignment - such as the last 19 questions you have asked, all of which are straight from the assignments. EAIT does not take kindly to this, and I direct you to the [Academic Integrity and Plagiarism policy](http://www.uq.edu.au/myadvisor/academic-integrity-and-plagiarism)

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)$ is a finite subset of $Z^+$ and $1\in f(x).$ The usual notation is that $P(S)$ is the set of ALL subsets of $S.$

(1). $\;f:Z^+\to P(Z^+)$ is  NOT onto. $f$ does not even map $Z^+$ onto the set of all finite  $A\in P(Z^+)$ that have $1$ as a member: E.g.,if $2\in f(x)$ and $3\in f(x)$ then $6\in f(x)$ so no $x$ satisfies $f(x)=\{1,2,3\}.$

(2).$\;f$ IS 1-to-1 . We have  $x\in f(y)\implies x\leq y.$ So if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ then $(x_1\in f(x_1)=f(x_2)\implies x_1\leq x_2)$ and $(x_2\in f(x_2)=f(x_1)\implies x_2\leq x_1).$

So $f(x_1)=f(x_2)\implies x_1\leq x_2\leq x_1.$